# how to select event_type using group by didmd5

Tags: mysql

```
 events_id | didmd5                          | article_id | event_type | count | datetime   | last_updated        |
+-----------+---------------------------------+------------+------------+-------+------------+---------------------+
|         1 | f8fdf8b7315c884b87361a4dd73d878 |          5 | share      |     1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-01 08:40:40 |
|         2 | f8fdf8b7315c884b87361a4dd73d878 |          5 | like       |     1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-01 08:42:26 |
|         3 | f8fdf8b7315c884b87361a4dd73d878 |          5 | read       |     1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-01 08:42:33 |
|         4 | f8fdf8b7315c884b87361a4dd73d878 |          5 | readmore   |     2 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-01 08:47:07 |
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the different event_type in one row you can try :

```
SELECT didmd5, group_concat(event_type) from TABLE group by didmd5;
```

Comment: |article_id | like  | read | share | readmore|
    5         | 1  | 1    |    1   |         2     |
 I am looking answer like this